# Handling Date Times returned from web service

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Hi I have a web service that I am querying using vb.net to return some values which includes a datetime value This value may represent a date which was recorded by a device outside of the uk. if I look at the date it looks like #8/5/2016 06:55:00 AM# I have some concerns about the accuracy of the dates being returned and have asked the technical support people form the web service for advice and they have provided the information below which suggests that I need to cast the date to a UTC date type and remove the local time zone in order to get accurate data. I have read articles https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx on msdn etc in order to try and get a grasp of the solution but I am still in the dark! I have reproduced the advice given below can you help me with a solution how would I code the retrieval of the data in order to do what is suggested?

Advice Given
Using the method outlined below, by removing the local PC time zone offset, will give you the correct time of the event. You can then convert that time data object to UTC and that time difference between the UTC and received time will give you the time zone offset.

E.g. Event occurs at 07:00 (UTC+1)
1. Retrieve date time – object has its time zone (+1) plus local PCs time zone(+1) – 08:00
2. Remove local PC time zone – object now only has its time zone (+1) – 07:00
3. Convert this date time object to UCT – object now has time zone of +0 – 06:00
4. Difference between original date time object after removing the local PC time zone and object in Point 3 above will give you the time zone of the original event – 01:00

Comment: Does the web service really return a *text string* instead of a date value?  Is that May 8 or August 5 2016 ? Is this local time or UTC? This is a serious bug on the service's side. The web service should return a value using the ISO8601 format, ie `2016-08-05T06:55:00Z` for UTC time or `2016-08-05T06:55:00+01:00` for values in a specfic timezone, like Britain on summer time.

Comment: To put it another way, Web services (ie SOAP) and REST services use ISO8601 for dates. The creators of the service had to go out of their way to break compatibility.

Comment: The service returns a datetime value  <EventDate>dateTime</EventDate> I am querying the service which returns a collection of events. If I debug and drill into the value the date I provided is what I get from the object or at least what vs provides. it is August the 5th.

Comment: The service soap is here http://api.fm-web.co.uk/webservices/EventNotificationWebSvc/EventNotificationWS.asmx?op=GetNotificationsSinceID

Comment: Please post your actual code. I suspect  what you posted is how a DateTime property in the deserialized object date appears in your debugger, not the actual value. In which case, you don't have to parse anything. Also post an actual XML response, at least the part the actual value. It may *already* contain an offset or UTC indicator (Z). If that's the case, you may not have to do much. For example, the *deserialized* DateTime value may already be UTC with DateTimeKind.Utc.

Comment: Hi thank you for your contribution to my question,  I have been able to work out the code required to achieve my goal.  You are correct in your assumption that there may be a offset indicator!  My final code looks like. 


   Dim currentUTC As DateTime = localZone.ToUniversalTime(temp1.RecordedDateTime)
                            Dim currentOffset As TimeSpan = localZone.GetUtcOffset(temp1.RecordedDateTime)

                            Dim truedate As DateTime = currentUTC.ToLocalTime

Comment: If you post your last comment as an answer to my issue I will credit you with the solution.

Comment: don't forget that time-zones offsets can change, and also change at different times and change relative to one another - since I battled with these concepts once.  If you paid a person according to UTC, he would get paid the same if the clocks change, but if you use local time he can gain or lose an hour (which is what is done in reality I found)

Comment: Thank you Andrew I have noted your observation.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton offsets change but not for past dates. The current and past rules for such changes are known. That's why times are typically accompanied by the *IANA timezone name*, not the offset, eg `Europe/London` instead of +0 or +1. Storing UTC only doesn't help if you actually need a local time - eg your flight departs based on local, not UTC time. Which is why libraries like NodaTime actually work with IANA timezones.